# quote + on bash command line when argument for grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep, escaping

Can someone please clarify what is happening here.

I have a text file like this:

```
$ more text3.txt
daaaaaad
dead
dad
dd
did
deed
drd
duuuurd
```

If on the command line I issue this command:

```
$ grep "^d[aei]\+d$" text3.txt
daaaaaad
dead
dad
did
deed
```

I get the results I expect.  Same if I use single quotes around 1st grep argument.

If I remove the `\` before the `+` then I get NO results from grep.

The thing that is confusing me is that after `[aei]` grep would be quite fine with `+` and it interprets it as one or many of previous character class.  So why do I need to escape the `+` character?  Is it because bash has a problem with it?

I get same behavior out of interest on Windows using `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You should *always* use `grep -E` (or `egrep`) so that `grep` uses *extended* regular expressions. That way you don't need to quote most of the special characters.

Comment: @ooga Thanks for the -E / egrep tip

Comment: Worth noting -- `man grep` claims that direct invocation of `egrep` is deprecated (albeit still provided), and also provides "Matcher Selection" flags (such as the `-E` toggle) and a variety of other info worth reading/skimming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+` without escaping it, grep looks for the character `+` after a single character from the set `[aei]`, which doesn't occur in your sample text file. When you escape `\+` then you convey the "one or more occurrences" flag to grep.

Similar behavior applies to other special grep symbols, such as `grep "dad\|dead" text3.txt"` to grep for "dad" or "dead".

Some additional info about **BRE** (Basic Regular Expressions) vs **ERE** (Extended Regular Expressions) can be found (among other places) [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), with the key takeaway being that BRE uses backslash "to give the metacharacter its flavor" whereas ERE uses backslash "to suppress the meaning of metacharacters".

Comment: So basically the escaping gives the following symbol special meaning?

Comment: Yeah, though I'd phrase it that the escaping flags the symbol for grep to interpret it as an operational instruction rather than as a character literal.

Comment: Normal grep uses `BRE` to parse input file. This is the reason for why a `+` in grep command need to esacped inorder to match one or more times of preceding character.

Comment: @AvinashRaj -- Thanks, that's helpful info. I admit I had to Google BRE (not realizing that your answer included a three-word phrase corresponding with that acronym), so I updated my answer to spell out some info about the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Normal grep uses a basic regular expression to parse the input files. In BRE, you need to escape `+`, so that it would work as intended(*ie; one or more*). If you use `-P` or `E` parameter with grep then you don't need to escape `+`(in this `\+` means literal +)

`grep` with single quotes won't support variable expansion but grep with double quotes support variable expansion.

**Example:**

```
$ f=v; grep '$f' file
$ f=v; grep "$f" file
v
```